# new MAAS nodes are only provisioned from one pod

Tags: juju, maas, kvm-virtualization

I have two pods in my MAAS deployment. Both are 32 core, 64 GB ram machines running CentOS and KVM and configured for MAAS access via virsh.

I've noticed that MAAS only uses one of my pods for composing new nodes, even when the utilized pod is over-commissioned.

[image: after deploying two copies of canonical-kubernetes]

I have verified that I can manually compose a node on my unused pod, but when I deploy new software using `juju` only the one pod is used.

Does this seem like expected behavior? How can I tell MAAS to balance the load between all available pod resources? Is there a way to mark a pod as unusable for just in time node composing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVM allows over committing of resources, so does MAAS. Future versions of MAAS will allow setting the over committing rate, allowing you to fallback to different pods.

That said, the MAAS API does support specifying which pod you can allocate a machine from, but I do not believe juju does today.

Comment: thanks - so in future versions I could set the over commit rate to 1:1, and when resources are exhausted on a pod the next available pod's resources would be consumed? any idea when that feature will be released?